# Opened HTML select box has wrong position in Firefox

Tags: html, css, html-select

I am developing a form and the  element shows strange positioning mistakes in FIREFOX. Once the user clicks to see all options, the list positions at a completely different place in the HTML document.

[image: Problem description]

Can anybody tell me what the problem could be, or better: How can I influence the position of the "option-list" in order to fix the problem?

Comment: strange, never experienced this before !

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score -1):

Just having same issue.
In my case, the form is inside floating box with this css: perspective: 1000px;

When you remove this css, it works. Is that firefox bug?

If there is animation and you want to keep it, the solution could be to set perspective property only for the moment when animation is performed.